# jQuery UI color picker issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I want to create a color picker, but it needs to be horizontal like this
http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/
It needs to be a horizontal slider that can scroll through all colors. I am trying to base it off the jquery ui slider.

Does anyone know any examples of this from the web?
Or could tell me how to do this?

I was thinking based on the distance the slider is set say 50% i would need to convert that value into a color value.

Something like 0% distance is white and 100% is black.

Note: it needs to be 1 slider that can range through `all` colours, and the colors has to be smooth transition not all randomed.

Like this image:
[image]
but it somehow needs to incorporate white and black in it.

Answer (score 1):

You can represent HTML colors as hex values. With this in mind, we can create a slider that goes from `#000000` to `#FFFFFF` (or 0 to 16777215 in decimal):

```
$("#slider").slider({
    min: 0,
    max: 16777215,
    slide: function (event, ui) {
        var hex = "#" + ui.value.toString(16);
        $("#color").css("background-color", hex);
    }
});
```

Note that for this to be remotely usable, you would have to have a pretty long slider. To get a better sense of it working, use the keyboard arrows instead of the mouse to slide through colors.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/4extL/46/

Comment: this is basically what I am looking for, but the problem is the color transitions are not smooth, this is too random. Is there a way to make it smoother?

Comment: I updated the first post with a picture of what I am looking for, but it needs the white and black colors in it as well...

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking for is possible. I hope someone comes along and proves me wrong though

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of jQuery UI examples [here](http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/12137750/ColorPicker) for color pickers. They even have examples where you can scroll through all the colors. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible. I would recommend using one of the many jQuery colorpicker plugins. Or you could look at this jQuery UI example - not exactly what you wanted but it does use the jQueryUI slider: http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#colorpicker